# Почему оно не работает?

Tags: javascript

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function Coffee(roast, ounces, getSize, toString) {
   this.roast = roast;
   this.ounces = ounces;
   this.getSize = function (){
     if (this.ounces = 8) {
  alert("small");
} else if (this.ounces = 12) {
  alert("medium");
  }  else if(this.ounces = 16){
    alert("large");
  }
  };
this.toString =  function (){
  if (this.ounces = 8) {
console.log("You ordered a small cup");
} else if (this.ounces = 10) {
  console.log("You ordered a medium cup");
}
else if(this.ounces = 12){
  console.log("You ordered a large cup");
     }
    };
}

  var houseBlend = new Coffee("House Blend", 12);
  var darkRoast = new Coffee("Dark Roast", 16);

  var cups = [houseBlend, darkRoast];
  for (var i = 0; i < cups.length; i++) {
   cups[i].getSize();
   cups[i].toString();

  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//if (this.ounces = 8) {
if (this.ounces == 8) {
```

Comment: Я этого вообще не замечал, впредь буду внимательней

Comment: Всё-таки йода-стайл не на пустом месте возник)